# Deserializing OData.Error messages

Tags: c#, json, json.net, odata, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an ASP.NET application that uses the Azure AD Graph API. Often, when an invalid operation is performed against the Graph API, an exception is thrown.

The following code shows an invalid Graph API call that would trigger an exception:

```
// Query the Azure AD User
var userToUpdate = await activeDirectoryClient.Users.GetByObjectId("user@domain.net").ExecuteAsync();

// Set given name to an empty string (not allowed)
userToUpdate.GivenName = "";

try
{
    // Update the user in Azure AD
    await userToUpdate.UpdateAsync();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Return exception message
}
```

The message of the inner exception is a JSON string with forward slashes before each quotation mark. It looks something like this:

```
"{\"odata.error\":{\"code\":\"Request_BadRequest\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en\",\"value\":\"Invalid value specified for property 'givenName' of resource 'User'.\"},\"values\":[{\"item\":\"PropertyName\",\"value\":\"givenName\"},{\"item\":\"PropertyErrorCode\",\"value\":\"InvalidValue\"}]}}"
```

Attaching a screenshot of the Locals window where the exception message is found:
[image: Exception details]

I would like to convert this JSON to a .NET object to return informative error details. I am using the JSON.NET library for this, and I am assuming that the JSON will deserialize to an `ODataError` object:

```
var error = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ODataError>(e.InnerException.Message);
```

However, the deserialized object always has a value of `null`, which means that the conversion is not working as expected.

That being said, what class should the above JSON string map to? Also, should I be removing the forward slashes from the string for proper deserialization?

Comment: What are you trying to do? How are you making the OData call and what client do you use? What is the type of the exception? An ODataErrorException already has an [Error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.odata.core.odataerrorexception.error(v=vs.113).aspx#P:Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataErrorException.Error) property with the deserialized error. In any other case, the exception messages will contain specific messages generated by your client (probably after deserializing any specific error messages), not the raw Json part. You need to read the response to get to the raw json

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for your comment. I've updated the question with some more code samples, and I hope I clarified what I am trying to accomplish. Please let me know if I need to explain any part of it further.

Comment: You still haven't explained - what is the type of the exception thrown? If it's ODataErrorException, you don't have to do anything, just catch the correct exception type. As for the raw Json, you won't find it in the exception object.

Comment: Sorry, the exception type is `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException`, and its inner exception is of type `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException`. The JSON string in the question is the message of the InnerException. That is why I'm having difficulty determining what type of exception to convert the string to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you've got null after deserialization is your JSON object properties names differs from `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.ODataError` class properties names - "odata.error" property can not be deserialized to Error property of Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.ODataError

As workaround I've added my own types for correct deserialization:

```
internal class ODataError
    {
        [JsonProperty("odata.error")]
        public ODataErrorCodeMessage Error { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ODataErrorCodeMessage
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }

        public ODataErrorMessage Message { get; set; }

        public List<ExtendedErrorValue> Values { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ExtendedErrorValue
    {
        public string Item { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ODataErrorMessage
    {
        public string Lang { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

After that JSON message was properly deserialized:

```
...
    try
    {
        await ADClient.Users.AddUserAsync(newUser);
        return Result.Ok();
    }
    catch (DataServiceRequestException ex)
    {
        var innerException = ex.InnerException;
        var error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ODataError>(innerException.Message);
        return Result.Fail(new Error(error.Error.Message.Value, error.Error.Code, ex));
    }
```

Comment: Do you still need to create your own types for deserialization or has Microsoft made an update to this?